# React - hovering over dynamically generated component calls render method

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, react-google-maps

My app contains a google map that displays markers based on coordinates from an API. Upon the loading the app, an API request is made and a few coordinates are grabbed to be displayed on the screen. The API data is mapped to a `<Marker />` component.

Problem: Upon hovering over any Marker, the render method gets called again and the Markers quickly flash. Why?

Map.js

```
state = {
    center: { lat, lng },
    zoom: defaultZoom,
    showingInfoWindow: false,
    selectedMarker: ""
  };

onMarkerHover = (e, marker) => {
    this.setState({
      selectedMarker: marker.recordid,
      showingInfoWindow: true
    });
    this.onSendMarkerInfoToParent();
  };

render() {
    const data = this.props.searchedResponse;
    console.log("rerendering"); // printed in console on every hover event
    const Markers = props =>
      data
        ? data.data.records.map(marker => {
            return (
              <Marker
                position={{ lat: marker.fields.geom.coordinates[1], lng: marker.fields.geom.coordinates[0] }}
                key={marker.recordid}
                onClick={e => this.onMarkerClick(e, marker)}
                onMouseOver={e => this.onMarkerHover(e, marker)}
              >
                {this.state.showingInfoWindow && this.state.selectedMarker === marker.recordid && (
                  <InfoWindow
                    className="info-window"
                    position={{ lat: marker.fields.geom.coordinates[1], lng: marker.fields.geom.coordinates[0] }}
                  >
                    <div>{rateTimeCalc(marker)}</div>
                  </InfoWindow>
                )}
              </Marker>
            );
          })
        : null;
    return (
      <div className="map-container">
        <LoadScript googleMapsApiKey={process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_KEY}>
          <GoogleMap id="map" center={this.state.center} zoom={this.state.zoom}>
            <Markers />
          </GoogleMap>
        </LoadScript>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

App.js

```
onSendMarkerInfoToParent = e => {
    console.log("parent", e);
  };
```

Comment: what function onMarkerHover does?

Comment: I added the method. basically it shows the `<InfoWindow>` and sends the `marker` object back to parent

Comment: you change showingInfoWindow: true onMarkerHover  and it wil rerender all markers

Comment: why does it affect all of them?

Comment: because  you are working with showingInfoWindow  state in iterations with all Markers

Comment: that makes sense. what is an alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of Lifecycle of React app.
You have mapped the onHover method in your code that set the state.

```
onMouseOver={e => this.onMarkerHover(e, marker)}

onMarkerHover = (e, marker) => {
    this.setState({
      selectedMarker: marker.recordid,
      showingInfoWindow: true
    });
    this.onSendMarkerInfoToParent();
  };
```

This setState causes re-render.

In React, whenever you set the state of a component. The render method will be executed automatically.
[image] 
You can read this article for reference: https://medium.com/react-ecosystem/react-components-lifecycle-ce09239010df.

Answer (score 1):

Solution for google-maps-react and  Markers re-rendering:

1.Create Wrapper PureComonent for all Markers.

2.Maintain one InfoWindow for all Markers.

Working example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/falling-wave-kjcee